# React-Native loading state not updating when fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I've had this problem for a while and tried everything I could think of but so far I haven't found anything to solve this yet. When fetching data from my database I set my loading state to true and when I'm done I set it back to false, now the problem is that it never gets set to true. In the code example, I've delayed the fetch for 5 seconds so that it simulates slow internet to see the loading indicator and state change if it would work.

Edit: I'm using firebase firestore to get my data. to be more specific I use onsnapshot listener which is not asynchronous so I can't use async. I also removed the try-catch block since this has no use either, yet still, the loading state is not set to true before I call the database.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      setTimeout(() => {
       //fetchting from database.
      }, 5000);
      return () => {
        /* unsubscribe(); */
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

Edited function:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      firebase.db
        .collection("collectionname")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          //handeling data returned.
        })},
      5000
    );
    setLoading(false);
    return () => {
      /* unsubscribe(); */
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How your code is executing is the important thing here. Your first `setLoading` runs and is set to `true`. Then, your `setTimeout` is **initialized** but (and here is where the problem is) immediately following the initialization of your `setTimeout` command, `setLoading` is called again and set to false because there is no break after the initalization of `setTimeout`. So, the loading is set to true before your db is called, but it is immediately set to false before anything has a chance to happen because of the execution order of your code.

Try setting your `setLoading(false)` within the setTimeout like so:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      firebase.db
        .collection("collectionname")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          //handeling data returned.
        });

        //moved setLoading to within final setTimeout execution
        setLoading(false);
        },
      5000
    );
    
    return () => {
      /* unsubscribe(); */
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Okay but what if im not using timeout because in production this is not used.

Comment: Then you run `setLoading(false)` after everything is done loading and it's ready for user interaction. If you have to wait for any more data, build any DOM elements, or do anything that hinders user interaction, then wait until all of that is done to run `setLoading(false)`. It looks like you would do it at some point during your `onSnapshot` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `setLoading(false)` will be called before the data (5 second wait) has ran. Here, you can `await` a `Promise` of a 5 second wait (in production you would use `fetch` or similar). Now, the `finally` block won't run until *after* the promise resolves.

```javascript
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      // get data (waiting 5 seconds for example)
      // note `await` - the `finally` won't run until after this has resolved
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000))
      return () => {
        // unsubscribe()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
  getData()
}, []);
```

Edit: Since you are getting the data through a callback, you need to wrap it in a promise so you can `await` it, like so:

```javascript
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const snapshot = await new Promise(resolve => 
        firebase.db
          .collection("collectionname")
          .onSnapshot(resolve)
      )
      return () => {
        // unsubscribe()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
  getData()
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question so it's more clear.

Comment: @BertVanHecke I have edited my post to implement the firestore call. I have not used firestore but I think the new solution should work.